# Derivative of Euclidean distance in 3D

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am currently working on a problem involving the gradient of a composite function with respect to a single particle $k$, following

$$
\nabla_k u(r_{k,i})
$$
for which $r_{k,i} = |\mathbf{r}_k - \mathbf{r}_{i}|$. This far I have worked out

$$
\nabla_k u(r_{i,k}) = \frac{\partial u(r_{i,k})}{\partial r_{i,k}} \frac{\partial r_{i,k}}{\partial \mathbf{r}_k}
=
u'(r_{i,k})\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{r}_k}
|\mathbf{\mathbf{r_k}} - \mathbf{r_i}|
$$
Could I treat the last partial differential operation like one would treat an absolute value function in 1D? Or would I have to expand the radial variable into its Cartesian coordinates and work from there?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When computing such partials, I find it easier to differentiate $|\mathbf{r}_k-\mathbf{r}_i|^2=(\mathbf{r}_k-\mathbf{r}_i)\cdot (\mathbf{r}_k-\mathbf{r}_i)$ since then (for instance) 
$$
\partial_{x_1} |\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^2
=2 (\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)\cdot \partial_{x_1} (\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)=2 (\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)\cdot \hat{x}= 2(x_1-x_x).$$ (The point is really that the squared distance is a quadratic function of the arguments rather than the square-root of such.)

Answer (score 1):

By taking the partial derivatives, the gradient of

$$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$$ is

$$\frac{(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}}=\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0|}.$$